# HTML forms: Prevent leave page warning pop-up and reset form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I spent a few days and got a form working on my website.
However whenever it is submitted, it does not reset and when I reload the browser it sends the form again using the previous submitted data.

How would I stop/prevent this?

I also want to get rid of the leave page warning that pops up when there is any data written in the form. So that users can leave the page without the pop-up even if there is data not submitted.

The form is commented out on this temporarily page: http://rikahiyuka.com/Template%20-%20index.php

(I don't have much time to type this question so I might change it later)

Comment: We need some code in order to help you.

Comment: spaces in URL's are a bad practice, replace them by dashes or underscores for example

Comment: I understand that spaces should be avoided. Its is only used in this occasion because the form code was only on that put aside page (supposed to be unused/template) but since I was at school I cannot change the filename because I cannot connect to my webhost.

Answer (score 1):

To clear your form on submit, you can add some Javascript to the form element itself, e.g.:

```
<form onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

To prevent the warning on page exit, have you tried:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks  a lot for this. window.onbeforeunload = null; fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JavaScript [onbeforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).  It's non-standard JavaScript introduced by Microsoft, however it works in most browsers and [their onbeforeunload documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx) has more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="MAILTO:contact@rikahiyuka.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

You cannot POST to a `mailto:` url. You should have the action set to a PHP page, which sent the email for you. There are many examples for a PHP contact form on the internet.

Comment: You can use method=post with a mailto: URL. It's very primitive, but it's even part of HTML5 CR. And this answer does not address the question at all.

Comment: It is possible, but it just passes the variable into the body of the email. Which is probably not what he is looking for.